# XML Schema for document with two namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to prepare .xsd to validate XML document I was given.

In bespoken document there are defined two namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <komunikat xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="www.example.com/xml"
        xmlns:nfz="www.example.com/xml/nfz" 

        nfz:version="1.7"
        nfz:info-aplik-nad="KS-PPS 2016.00.3.1">

        type="someType"
        version="4"
    </komunikat>
```

In my schema I tried:

```
   targetNamespace="www.example.com/xml"
   xmlns:nfz="www.example.com/xml/nfz"
   ...
   <xs:attribute name="nfz:info-aplik-nad" use="optional" >
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="40" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType> ...
```

But in my validator I receive an error :

```
.XMLSchemaParseError: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attribute', attribute 'name': 'nfz:info-aplik-nad' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:NCName'., line 25
```

What I understand `:` char is not allowed in `attribute` name property.

Is it possible to do without changing xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only attributes in namespaces can have colons in their names (to specify the namespace prefix).

There are a number of extraneous problems with your XML and XSD.  Here is a complete, more minimal, example that shows an XML instance that is valid against an XSD where an attribute is in a namespace:

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<komunikat xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns="http://myNameSpace.com" 
           xmlns:nfz="http://myNameSpace.com" 
           nfz:info-aplik-nad="KS-PPS 2016.00.3.1"/>
```

### XSD

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://myNameSpace.com" 
           xmlns:m="http://myNameSpace.com"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           attributeFormDefault="qualified" >
  <xs:element name="komunikat">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence/>
      <xs:attribute name="info-aplik-nad" use="optional" >
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="18" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Note in particular the use of `attributeFormDefault="qualified"` in the XSD.

In order to use an additional namespace, you must have an additional XSD, which then would imported (using `xs:import`) into the main XSD.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to achieve what I wanted with `.xml` unaltered.
Now I have two `.xsd`. First got `mainNameSpace` which imports second with `secondaryNameSpace`. I use attributes defined in second `.xsd` using `ref=` with defined in `xmlns:nfz="secondNameSpace"` prefix. I don't clearly understand `attributeFormDefault`. But following logic that when it's qualified it needs prefix, doesn't otherwise. I set `attributeFormDefault="qualified"` in secondary `.xsd` and left ot to default `unqualified` in first one. Which allowed me to sucessfully validate my `.xml`. Thanks